# Why is the ImportJSON function limited by the SUBSTITUTE function to only show the first entry?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A further question to this topic:

If I `ImportJSON` with an added `SUBSTITUTE` function for more than one entry, it only shows the first entry

---

That's my code now:

```
=(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(ImportJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?localization=false&tickers=true&market_data=true&community_data=true&developer_data=true&sparkline=true";"/market_data/price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency/usd,/market_data/price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency/eur";"noHeaders");".";",")))
```

I want to substitute the "." for ";" so I can show some of the parsed values as percentage. But of course I still want all the other data from the JSON to be shown.

---

Is there maybe another way to format imported `JSON` data? - Without referencing them in another table and formatting them there.

Comment: At a quick glance, my first instinct would be to recommend looking at the [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) and [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) functions, as those often help with operating on imported data sets and cell ranges. Both are finicky in their own unique ways, but they might be a place to start if you haven't looked at them.

Comment: I don't think you can make execute `substitute` against a feed. There's a certain contraction; if you had copy/paste the data, then that might be a different thing altogether.